# Overwrite a slice of a timeseries with a value

Tags: python-polars

I have some timeseries data in the form of a `pl.DataFrame` object with a datetime col and a data col. I would like to correct an error in the data that occurs during a distinct time range by overwriting it with a value.

Now in `pandas`, one would use the datetimes as index and slice that timerange and assign to it, like so

```py
df.loc[start_dt_string:end_dt_string, column_name] = some_val
```

Being completely new to `polars` I have a hard time figuring out how to express this. I tried selecting rows with `.filter` and `.is_between` but of course this doesn't support assignment. How would one go about doing this with `polars`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I missed this in the docs, so RTFM to the rescue. In the [corresponding section](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/coming_from_pandas.html#column-assignment-based-on-predicate) of the `Coming from Pandas` guide, this case is covered almost verbatim:

```py
df.with_column(
    pl.when(pl.col("c") == 2)
    .then(pl.col("b"))
    .otherwise(pl.col("a")).alias("a")
)
```

The above `pandas` example uses timerange slicing, so for the sake of completeness I'm going to add `polars` code that does exactly the same:

```py
df.with_column(
    pl.when(pl.col(dt_column_name).is_between(
        datetime(start_dt_string),
        datetime(end_dt_string),
        include_bounds=True
    ).then(pl.lit(some_val))
    .otherwise(pl.col(column_name))
    .alias(column_name)
)
```